# Embedding Twitter widget on HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have copied  this from https://publish.twitter.com/# but not work properly only shows "A Twitter List by TwitterDev". What can I do now?

A Twitter List by TwitterDev

Comment: I too have the similar issue. Did you get that working?